# When should Haskell's Data.Map be used in favor of a list of tuples?

Tags: performance, haskell

Recently I needed to compare two sets of historical data. Since sometimes a day or two was missing in one of them and I wanted to be precise, I decided to create a list of all possible dates and two lists of tuples containing dates and corresponding values belonging to both sets. Then I changed the latter lists to `Map`s in order to improve date lookups.

The idea was to try to find every date from the full dates list in both `Map`ped list and create a list of "triples" of `(date, value1, value2)` containing only dates where both data sets had a date and a value. Then I could write them to a file and properly compare them.

**DON'T MIND THE CODE, IT'S INCLUDED ONLY FOR GOOD MEASURE**

Here is the code (it is not optimal at all, but for that small task it did its job nicely):

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.List (transpose)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

main = do
    dts     <- readFile "dates.txt"
    cts1    <- readFile "eu.txt"
    cts2    <- readFile "usa.txt"
    let
        dates  = lines dts
        cols1  = transpose $ map words $ lines cts1
        cols2  = transpose $ map words $ lines cts2
        prs1   = zip (head cols1) (last cols1)
        prs2   = zip (head cols2) (last cols2)
        map1   = M.fromList prs1
        map2   = M.fromList prs2
        trips  = map fromJust (filter (/=Nothing) (map (\date -> getTrips date map1 map2) dates))
        cols3  = map (\(a,b,c) -> [a,b,c]) trips
        result = unlines $ map unwords $ cols3
    writeFile "trips.txt" result

getTrips :: String -> M.Map String String -> M.Map String String -> Maybe (String, String, String)
getTrips date map1 map2
    | is1 /= Nothing && is2 /= Nothing    = Just (date, fromJust is1, fromJust is2)
    | otherwise                           = Nothing
    where
        is1 = M.lookup date map1
        is2 = M.lookup date map2
```

TL;DR: The code worked (though I would gladly hear some opinions/advice), but I have some questions:

- there were only around 2000 dates, therefore I didn't care much about performance (you can see that I was using `String`s everywhere); was using `Data.Map` an overkill then? **When should `Data.Map` be preferred over lists of tuples?**
- the `Map` was created from tuples of `String`s - is it fine or **should the key always be numeric in order for the balancing and lookups to work properly?**

Comment: If you're using a list of tuples as a key-value map, you're probably better off with `Data.Map`. The key can be any `Ord` type and it will work fine, but for more specific types there might be something better than `Data.Map` you could use instead, such as some flavor of trie.

Comment: Well, I guess you could say that it was a key-value case; I was wondering if in a general situation when one must search for values using some index it is considered a good practice to always use `Map` or some other specialized type instead of the naive tuple list, even if the problem isn't big - or rather when a `Map` becomes necessary.

Comment: When it becomes *necessary* is something that can really only be answered based on profiling and the specific needs of your program. That said, the only time I would use a list of tuples is if I was doing something `Data.Map` and friends don't support, such as searching on either component (i.e., a bidirectional multimap).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> there were only around 2000 dates, therefore I didn't care much about
>   performance (you can see that I was using Strings everywhere); was
>   using Data.Map an overkill then? When should Data.Map be preferred
>   over lists of tuples?

You should use data structures that fit your problem and performance/programming-time constraints, so using a `Map` was probably a good idea. Maybe in your case if your data was already ordered you could have done

```
union [] _ = []
union _ [] = []
union xss@((dx,vx):xs) yss@((dy,vy):ys) = 
    case compare dx dy of
         EQ -> (dx, vx, vy) : union xs ys
         GT -> union xss ys
         LT -> union xs yss
```

> the Map was created from tuples of Strings - is it fine or should the
>   key always be numeric in order for the balancing and lookups to work
>   properly?

No, if your code typechecks your `Map` will work properly (w/r/t the way you've defined `Ord` instance). But as  C. A. McCann suggests, a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) may be more appropriate if your keys are lists, especially if there is much overlap between key prefixes (look at how the `Ord` instance on lists is implemented, and imagine the number of operations that have to take place to insert the keys "abcdx", "abcdy", and "abcdz" into a `Map` vs. a trie structure to convince yourself).

Comment: I like your union proposal **a lot**; as the data was already sorted, I totally prefer this simple and clever solution to the "well, it works" one. And the advice on considering a trie in such situations is spot-on, as date strings are very similar.